# Gradle 8 plugin-publish fails with "class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultSetProperty cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection" error

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I upgraded my Gradle version from 7.x to 8.x, and then tried to publish my plugin, I encountered the following vague error:

> Cause:
> class org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultSetProperty
> cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection (
> org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultSetProperty is in unnamed module of loader
> org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @66cd51c3;
> java.util.Collection is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'
> )

The only relevant changes I made was removing  the `pluginBundle` block:

```kotlin
pluginBundle {  
    website = "..."  
    vcsUrl = "..."  
    tags = listOf("...")  
}
```

And migrated them to the latest practice as these were moved to the `gradlePlugin` by the Gradle team to improve/simplify the process:

```kotlin
gradlePlugin {  
    website.set("...")  
    vcsUrl.set("...")  
  
    plugins {  
        create("...") {  
            id = project.group.toString()  
            displayName = project.name  
            description = project.description.toString()  
            implementationClass = "..."  
            tags.set(setOf("..."))  
        }  
    }}
```

These were nipped off straight from the official documentation, so I am surprised this is failing. If it helps, here are my relevant project dependency details:

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Kotlin | 1.8.10 |
| Java | 17 |
| Gradle | 8.0.2 |
| com.gradle.plugin-publish | 1.0.0 |
| io.github.gradle-nexus.publish-plugin | 1.1.0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade [com.gradle.plugin-publish](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.plugin-publish) to `1.1.x`. The version `1.0.0` had a critical bug that makes it fail when solely relying on the `gradlePlugin` block:

> Version 1.1.0 (latest)
>
> - Fix a bug in handling `tags`, when solely relying on `gradlePlugin` block for configuring plugin publication
> - Forbid bypassing the Maven Publish plugin for generating plugin publication metadata

See: [com.gradle.plugin-publish/1.1.0](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.plugin-publish/1.1.0)

The `pluginBundle` block was marked for removal in `8.0`. So when you upgraded from `7.x` you had to move these attributes to the `gradlePlugin`, that's why you encountered this error. You can also see this note in the [docs/publish-plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/publish-plugin) advising to upgrade:

> ***NOTE:** If you are using version *1.0.X* of the plugin, please update to at least version *1.1.0*, which contains critical bug fixes.*

So, simply upgrading to 1.1.x should resolve the problem...

Other helpful resources:

- [Gradle 8.0 Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/release-notes.html#promoted-features)
- [Upgrading your build from Gradle 7.x to 8.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html)